# How to ensure the text file will be read as Markdown file by an external user?

Tags: files, internet, mime-types, persistence, markdown

Mime type is set for `md` extension in the following file:

```bsh
$ cat /etc/mime.types | grep markdown
text/markdown                                   md markdown
```

But, on checking the Mime type of `.md` file it still shows as `text/plain`.

```bsh
$ file --mime-type -b Mime.md
text/plain
```

How can I make sure that all existing and newly generated `.md` files have `text/markdown` as the MIME type? Also, will the changed Mime type would persist if I email the file to a friend (who also happens to use the same filesystem as me - ext4 )?

---

Also the contents of `/usr/share/mime/text/markdown.xml` is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mime-type xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info" type="text/markdown">
  <!--Created automatically by update-mime-database. DO NOT EDIT!-->
  <comment>Markdown document</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="ast">Documentu Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="bg">Документ — Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="ca">document Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="cs">dokument Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="da">Markdown-dokument</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="de">Markdown-Dokument</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="el">Έγγραφο Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="en_GB">Markdown document</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="es">documento Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="eu">Markdown dokumentua</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="fi">Markdown-asiakirja</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="fr">document Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="ga">cáipéis Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="gl">documento de Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="he">מסמך Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="hr">Markdown dokument</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="hu">Markdown dokumentum</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="ia">Documento Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="id">Dokumen markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="it">Documento Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="ja">Markdown </comment>
  <comment xml:lang="kk">Markdown құжаты</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="ko">마크다운 문서</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="lv">Markdown dokuments</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="nl">Markdown document</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="oc">document Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="pl">Dokument Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="pt">documento Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="pt_BR">Documento Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="ru">Документ Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="sk">Dokument Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="sl">Dokument Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="sr">Маркдаун документ</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="sv">Markdown-dokument</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="tr">Markdown belgesi</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="uk">документ Markdown</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="zh_CN">Markdown 文档</comment>
  <comment xml:lang="zh_TW">Markdown 文件</comment>
  <sub-class-of type="text/plain"/>
  <glob pattern="*.md"/>
  <glob pattern="*.mkd"/>
  <glob pattern="*.markdown"/>
  <alias type="text/x-markdown"/>
</mime-type>
```

Comment: Use `mimetype` to determine the file type instead of `file`, which is hinted by this earlier post: [file command apparently returning wrong MIME type](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185216/125388). Perhaps OP actually wanted to ask "how to ensure the text file will be read as Markdown file by an external user?"

Comment: @clearkimura `$ mimetype -a Mime.md`
`Mime.md: text/markdown` `Mime.md: text/plain`. Can a file have multiple Mime (as shown in the above example)?

Comment: According to the manpage, `-a` option will "show output of all rules that match the file". You can include the debug option; run `mimetype -D -a filename.md` to see why it does so. Not sure if anyone would understand what you are trying to solve here; you should edit your question to clarify.